# Does it make sense to speak about a wavelength of the modes in a rectangular cavity?

Tags: electromagnetism, laser, cavity-qed

Let's consider the modes of the em field for an empty rectangular cavity.
In the electric field expression the physical meaning of $\nu=\omega/2\pi$ is clear, it is the time frequency of the wave.

On the other hand, $\lambda=2\pi/k$ doesn't have a clear physical meaning. For my textbook (principle of laser by Orazio Svelto), it should be the wavelength of the wave, but I don't understand, how it's possible to speak about a unique wavelength for these kind of em waves?
Instead, the parameters $k_x, k_y, k_z$ look some sort of wavelengths of the wave.

The be clear, I'm speaking about the following em field modes.
For a rectangular cavity of dimensions $a,b,c$ :
$$\vec E(x,y,z,t)=E_o \begin{bmatrix} e_x cos(k_x x) sen(k_y y) sen(k_z z) \\ e_y sin(k_x x) cos(k_y y) sen(k_z z) \\ e_z sin(k_x x) sen(k_y y) cos(k_z z)  \end{bmatrix} cos(wt+\phi)$$
with this condition:
$$\omega=kc$$
$$k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2=k^2$$
$$\vec k \cdot \vec e=0$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} k_x\\k_y\\k_z \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}l\pi/a\\m\pi/b \\ l\pi/c\end{bmatrix}$$
where $a,b,c$ are positive integer.

Comment: Does your textbook explicitly say that $k$ is the wavelength in a cavity, or does it only make the general statement $k=2\pi /\lambda$ (which is not general, it applies only to free space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a way of speaking, using the analogy with a well understood case of plane wave. As long as you understand what stands behind this (i.e. the equations that you wrote), this results in no ambiguity.